# Passing a Scalar reference into another Scalar

Tags: sql-server-2008, scalar

In SQL Server, I have a stored procedure that accepts a date parameter.  That date paramater is then passed along to another stored procedure.  However, the 2nd stored procedure parameter  is named as the first parameter.   and then I need to I have 2 different scalar variables:

```
DECLARE @date date, @sql varchar(100);

SET @date = '2012-07-01';
SELECT @sql = ('EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = '''+@date+'''')
```

I need the `@sql` scalar to contain this text so the stored procedure can call the other stored procedure:

`EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = '2012-07-01'`

But, when I run my code above, I get this error:

`Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.`

It's almost like I need to escape the `@date` operator.  Can this be done?

Side note:  Yes, I'm trying to dynamically pass along some variables.  I understand the dangers of doing so, but doing it this way is much simpler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date variable is being used in string concatenation, so it should be treated as a string, either through its declaration, a convert function, or a cast.  I tried this:

```
 DECLARE @date varchar(20), @sql varchar(100);
SET @date = '2012-07-01';
SELECT @sql = ('EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = ''' + @date + '''')

 PRINT @sql
```

and got this:

```
 EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = '2012-07-01'
```

I am stuck on 2005, so I don't have the date datatype, but when I tried to use datetime, I got this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Conversion failed when converting
>   datetime from character string.

You can also try

```
 DECLARE @date datetime, @sql varchar(100);
SET @date = '2012-07-01';
SELECT @sql = ('EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = ''' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @date, 102) + '''')
 PRINT @SQL;
```

and get

```
 EXEC pStoredprocedure @date = '2012.07.01'
```